# when fetching tmp directory it isn't give me the same result of the tmp files in cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel, temporary-files, tmp

I am using php function [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)   ,
when printing the results of this function, the results aren't the same as shown by manually opening tmp directory in cpanel
for example , the function gives me that there is a file called sess_10,  when searching for this name in cpanel ,i didn't find it despite the function retrieves it again when using it again , (i mean its not deleted), so why the results aren't the same?

Following is my code.

```
<?php
    print_r(scandir("/tmp"));
?>
```

Comment: Maybe it's a hidden file?

Comment: i tried to show them by enabling show hidden files property in cpanel settings , but still not found.

Comment: perhaps the two functions does not look into the same directory...

Comment: try this and let me know if you're still all those files `print_r(preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir("/tmp")) );`

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ it's perfect logic and i though that also , but i searched for the file names in cpanel main search box and also i tried to search for any temp folders anywhere but i didn't reached.

Comment: @bos570 : the same results sir.

Comment: Ok, Is the result from the scandir showing you any of your files that exist in that directory?

Comment: @bos570 : Never

Comment: Ok, so It's just looking in the wrong directory. '/tmp' might the base directory of your server root and might be different on your webroot

Comment: so on your cpanel the temp files showed are not from `/tmp`

Comment: try scandir("tmp"). When scanning /tmp it's done from root dir.

Comment: Where does '/tmp' actually exist? Can you share your directory structure?

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ but when using ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') And sys_get_temp_dir , they give me => /tmp

Comment: @Michael : the result of scandir('temp ') => Warning: scandir(tmp): failed to open dir: No such file or directory

Comment: @bos570 : tmp is in the same level of public html or var  , i mean the list like public html - var - tmp- and so on ,

Comment: please create a file in the temp folder from cpanel and see if it appears when you `scandir` from php

Comment: If tmp is at the same level as public html you will not get your desired result by using scandit on /tmp as /tmp is from the root. Try the scandir on the absolute path

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ : you are genius , the logic is very professional but the results didn't retrieve the manually created file .

Comment: so as i said before, the temp directory shown in cpanel is not `/tmp` this is not related to the config of php, each program can have its own temp directory

Comment: Use the absolute path. So something like `/home/user/www/tmp`

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ : you were correct, i was logging from two different sides, the first is from FTP connection and the second was from CPanel login, so normally they weren't the same door. actually, all of you were correct and I am really appreciating your time and efforts, thanks for all of you.

Comment: @Michael : thank you, I am appreciating your efforts and your time and i marked your comment as a useful answer for my question.

Comment: @bos570 : thank you Sir For your time and your efforts and iam appreciating your commentes and i marked your comment as a useful answer for my question.

Comment: In my case, i want to scandir the actual /tmp directory, but still php doesn't show existing file in it. It only shows owned tmp files

Answer (score 0):

systemd PrivateTmp?

```
$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service
```

change [Service]PrivateTmp from true to false.

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Then scandir( '/tmp' ) gave me same results as command ls /tmp in terminal.
Well, may be this is not a good idea for security.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely normal. Keep in mind that the /tmp directory is the global "tmp" of the server where your account is hosted.

If you need to check the "tmp" directory that's inside of your own cPanel, then you should use the follownig code instead:

```
<?php
print_r(scandir("/home/YOUR_CPANEL_USER_HERE/tmp"));
?>
```